How can I robustly combine URIs in C# to handle leading/trailing slashes?
I'm working on a C# project where I need to combine a base URL with various endpoints. However, I'm running into issues when the endpoint has a leading slash. For example:
string baseUrl = "https://example.com/api/v1/";
string endpoint = "/sessions/logon/";

Uri baseUri = new Uri(baseUrl);
Uri fullUri = new Uri(baseUri, endpoint);

Console.WriteLine(fullUri);

This code results in https://example.com/sessions/logon instead of the expected https://example.com/api/v1/sessions/logon. The leading slash in the endpoint causes it to override the base URL path.
Is there a robust way to combine URIs that correctly handles leading/trailing slashes?

Is there a robust way to combine URIs that correctly handles leading/trailing slashes? yes - use a library that does all that plus handles all the edge cases you haven’t thought of - eg https://flurl.dev/

I came up with a solution that involves creating an extension method to handle this scenario. Here’s the extension method I developed:
public static class UriExtension
{
    public static Uri Combine(this Uri baseUri, params string[] endpoints)
    {
        // Convert baseUri to string, trim it, and ensure it ends with a slash
        string baseUrl = baseUri.ToString().TrimEnd('/') + "/";

        // Trim each endpoint and join them with slashes
        string combinedPath = string.Join("/", endpoints.Select(e => e.Trim('/')));

        Uri fullUri = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), combinedPath);
        return fullUri;
    }
}

Usage
Here's how I use this extension method in my code. I've split the endpoint into parts just to illustrate the issue with the slashes:
Uri baseUri = new Uri("https://example.com/api/v1/");
string[] endpoints = { "/sessions/", "/logon/" };

Uri fullUri = baseUri.Combine(endpoints);
Console.WriteLine(fullUri);

This method ensures that no matter if the URIs have slashes at the beginning or end, they will be correctly combined into https://example.com/api/v1/sessions/logon/.
This solution has worked well for me, handling all variations of leading and trailing slashes gracefully.
